# Changing date month not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a list of payments and, if it must be done X times, I want to update the month by adding +1 to the previous date.

For example, a payment done 3 times monthly saved today:

- 03/05/2013
- 04/05/2013
- 05/05/2013

I have wrote this :

```
for payment in @order.payments
  if (payment.monthly)
    for month in 0..(payment.nb_of_times - 1)
      payment.date = payment.date.to_date >> month
      ordered_payment << payment
    end
  else
    ordered_payment << payment
  end
end
```

But the problem is it returns:

- 05/05/2013
- 05/05/2013
- 05/05/2013

Can you tell me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Rails way to implement your code:

```
@order.payments.each do |payment|
  if payment.monthly
    payment.nb_of_times.times do |nb_month|
      payment.date = payment.date + nb_month.months # this is awkward because of the variable name
      payment.save
      ordered_payment << payment
    end
  else
    ordered_payment << payment
  end
end
```

(The `.times` method is VERY usefull, for every Integer (Fixnum) you can call `.times` on it in order to iterate X times)

The other very usefull method we use here is `.months` which is available for Integers (Fixnum). It converts the Integer into a number of months in a Date. It also works for `.years`, `.hours`, `.weeks`, etc:

```
irb(main):008:0> Time.now + 1.years
#=> 2014-03-05 10:09:58 -0500
irb(main):009:0> Time.now + 1.months
#=> 2013-04-05 10:10:01 -0400
irb(main):010:0> Time.now + 1.hours
#=> 2013-03-05 11:10:04 -0500
irb(main):011:0> Time.now + 1.seconds
#=> 2013-03-05 10:10:08 -0500

# With a variable:
irb(main):014:0> Time.now + Patient.first.id.hours
  Patient Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" LIMIT 1
#=> 2013-10-08 06:12:04 -0400
```

Comment: With this line : `payment.date = payment.date.to_date >> month` I add a number of month in my date, for example "05/03/2013" >> 2 will return "05/05/2013"

Comment: It doesn't work too. I solved this by adding `payment_new = payment.dup` at the beginning of my times loop. It seems that the modification was done in payment AND in ordered_payment, like if ordered_payment was just a link to payment... strange. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I think you are -- that is, return an array of dates, subsequent to your `@order.payments` dates at month intervals, for `payment.nb_of_times` times, this should do the trick:

```
ordered_payment = []
@order.payments.each do |payment|
  if payment.monthly
    payment.nb_of_times.times do |i|
      ordered_payment << payment.date + (i+1).months
    end
  else
    ordered_payment << payment.date
  end
end
```

this should return an array of the dates.

Comment: Not really. I want to return an array of paiments. An example, I have a monthly payment which date is "05/03/2013" and nb_of times is 2. I would like with my fonction to return ordered_payment with two payments, one which start the "05/03/2013" and the other the "05/04/2013"